# Reproducing the 'non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access' exception

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, thread-safety

I have the following code described in https://dotnetfiddle.net/GknA5Q from a production application. The `dictionary` is used as a **cache** to keep the properties of an object. The **REST API** where this `dictionary` is used has hundreds of object types, so the cache gets larger when the API finds more object types. The properties from the object is retrieved via **reflection** as you see in the code. The `dictionary` gets populated when the API is started and hundreds of requests reach the API. Each request will have a object type whose properties are getting cached.

Although the REST API works, the code generates the following error now when the API starts in IIS. The line number that generates the error is 23 where `TryGetValue` is being called.

> Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.

I'm trying to reproduce the same error in a test application, so some solution can be applied. I don't want to remove the `dictionary` which will add time for processing every model in every request that reaches the API. If this `dictionary` cache is available, the properties can be retrieved from the cache instead of parsing through reflection.

How can I reproduce the above error?

Comment: Replace it with a `ConcurrentDictionary<Key, Value>` ?  Reproducing is going to be quite hit-or-miss.  You don't use testing to find out whether code is free of race conditions, you reason about it.

Comment: Race conditions are by their very nature very hard to reproduce (I've seen bugs like this surface once every 2 years). But clearly it _is_ happening. So swap to a ConcurrentDictionary right now, like @BenVoigt says (or use locking, depending on the nature of the problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class supports multiple readers but doesn't support multiple writers.

You can read the official documentation here: [Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class - Thread Safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2#thread-safety)

To test concurrency you may use the `Parallel` class: [Parallel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel)

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, i =>
{
     // dictionary.Add(...)
});
```

A thread-safe implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class:
[ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2)

You just need to replace `Dictionary` in you code with `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: `You just need to replace "Dictionary" in you code with "ConcurrentDictionary"` is overly simplistic (since some LINQ operators aren't thread-safe). But yes, as a general starting point better to switch.

Comment: I changed the ```Dictionary``` to ```ConcurrentDictionary``` and ran it concurrently with ```Parallel.For(...)```. I get the error **The key already existed in the dictionary**. If I change the ```dictionary.Add(...)``` to ```dictionary.AddOrUpdate(...)```, the error will go away?

Comment: Should I use ```dictionary.AddOrUpdate(...)``` when I use ```ConcurrentDictionary```?

Comment: Yes. Use AddOrUpdate instead of Add