# Getting a concurrent error on HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I've had this implementation a long time ago till I started receiving issues around it.

```
 private async Task AddHeaderInfo(string token, string reference="")
    {
        try
        {
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("VendorID", _appSettings.VendorId);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
 private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I can see from [Reproducing the 'non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037548/reproducing-the-non-concurrent-collections-must-have-exclusive-access-exceptio) something related to the implementation's use of the Dictionary class and that it has to be changed to ConcurrentDictionary.

I am confused, how do I apply that to my implementation since I am using the TryAddWithoutValidation method of httpClient?